# How to list handlers registered in boost::asio::io_service under debugger?

Tags: gdb, boost-asio

Given running application, I would like to extract information about currently registered complete handlers.

Handler has been registered by class A. For example:

```
boost::asio::async_read(s, b, boost::bind(&A::F, this->shared_from_this(), boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
```

Under debugger I have access to appropriate io_service variable. How to figure out (A::F, this, s, b) for operations, which have not yet completed.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I would like to slightly expand the scope of the question to cover alternatives for what I believe is the final goal: debugging asynchronous handlers.

---

#### Sample Program

To show debugging via examples, lets start with a basic UDP echo server that listens to port 4321:

```cpp
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::udp;

class udp_echo
{
public:
  udp_echo(boost::asio::io_service& service,
           unsigned int port)
    : socket_(service, udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), port))
  {
    socket_.async_receive_from(
      boost::asio::buffer(buffer_), sender_,
      boost::bind(&udp_echo::handle_receive, this,
                  boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                  boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
  }

  void handle_receive(const boost::system::error_code& error,
                      std::size_t bytes_transferred)
  {
    socket_.async_send_to(
      boost::asio::buffer(buffer_, bytes_transferred), sender_,
      boost::bind(&udp_echo::handle_send, this,
                  boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                  boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
  }

  void handle_send(const boost::system::error_code& error,
                   std::size_t bytes_transferred)
  {
    socket_.close();  
  }

private:
  udp::socket socket_;
  boost::array<char, 128> buffer_;
  udp::endpoint sender_;
};

int main()
{
  boost::asio::io_service service;
  udp_echo echo(service, 4321);
  service.run();
}
```

This simple program has a single asynchronous call chain:

```cpp
udp_echo::udp_echo()
{
  socket_.async_receive_from(...); --.
}                                    |
             .-----------------------'
             v
void udp_echo::handle_receive(...)
{
  socket_.async_send_to(...);  ------.
}                                    |
             .-----------------------'
             v
void udp_echo::handle_send()
{
  socket_.close(); 
}
```

---

#### Handler Tracking

Boost 1.47 introduced [handler tracking](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/handler_tracking.html).  Simply define `BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_HANDLER_TRACKING` and Boost.Asio will write debug output, including timestamps, to the standard error stream.  Running the programming, and sending "hello world" via UDP produced the following output:

```
@asio|1363273821.846895|0*1|socket@0xbf8c4e3c.async_receive_from // 1
@asio|1363273829.288883|>1|ec=system:0,bytes_transferred=12      // 2
@asio|1363273829.288931|1*2|socket@0xbf8c4e3c.async_send_to      // 3
@asio|1363273829.289013|<1|                                      // 4
@asio|1363273829.289026|>2|ec=system:0,bytes_transferred=12      // 5
@asio|1363273829.289035|2|socket@0xbf8c4e3c.close                // 6
@asio|1363273829.289075|<2|                                      // 7
```

It can be read line-by-line as:

1. Non-handler (0) invoked `socket.async_receive_from()`, creating handler 1.
2. Enter handler 1 `socket.async_receive_from()` with no error and 12 bytes have been received.
3. Handler 1 `socket.async_receive_from()` invoked `socket.async_send_to()`, creating handler 2.
4. Exit handler 1 `socket.async_receive_from()`.
5. Enter handler 2 `socket.async_send_to()` with no error and 12 bytes have been sent.
6. Handler 2 invoked `socket.close()`.
7. Exit handler 2 `socket.async_send_to()`.

And visually maps to the following:

```cpp
udp_echo::udp_echo()
{
  socket_.async_receive_from(...); --. // 1
}                                    |
             .-----------------------'
             v
void udp_echo::handle_receive(...)
{                                      // 2
  socket_.async_send_to(...);  ------. // 3
}                                    | // 4
             .-----------------------'
             v
void udp_echo::handle_send()
{                                      // 5
  socket_.close();                     // 6
}                                      // 7
```

---

### GDB

Debugging through GDB will require digging through multiple layers.  It helps to have an understanding of some of the implementation details of Boost.Asio.  Here are a few concepts:

- `io_service` only contains handlers that are ready to run.
- The `reactor` will generally contain work operations, and a handle to completion handlers that are not ready to run.
- The `reactor` will register itself with the `io_service`.

Here is a debug session:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00ab1402 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0x00237ab8 in __epoll_wait_nocancel () from /lib/libc.so.6
#2  0x080519c3 in boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor::run (this=0x80560b0, 
    block=true, ops=...)
    at /opt/boost/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/epoll_reactor.ipp:392
#3  0x08051c2d in boost::asio::detail::task_io_service::do_run_one (
    this=0x8056030, lock=..., this_thread=..., ec=...)
    at /opt/boost/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/task_io_service.ipp:396
#4  0x08051e8a in boost::asio::detail::task_io_service::run (this=0x8056030, 
    ec=...)
    at /opt/boost/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/task_io_service.ipp:153
#5  0x08051f50 in boost::asio::io_service::run (this=0xbfffe818)
    at /opt/boost/include/boost/asio/impl/io_service.ipp:59
#6  0x08049a44 in main () at example.cpp:48
(gdb) frame 6
#6  0x08049a44 in main () at example.cpp:48
48        service.run();
```

First, the reactor service will need to be located.  Downcasting will need to occur, so lets use the debugger to locate some types:

```
(gdb) p service.service_registry_.init_keytab
init_key
init_key<boost::asio::datagram_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::udp> >
init_key<boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor>
init_key<boost::asio::detail::task_io_service>
```

Each key is associated with a specific service, and all services are maintained in a linked list within `service.service_registry_`.  Type information is associated with them, allowing us to identify the desired service.

```
(gdb) set $service = service.service_registry_.first_service_
(gdb) p $service.key_.type_info_.__name
$1 = 0x8052b60
"N5boost4asio6detail14typeid_wrapperINS0_23datagram_socket_serviceINS0_2ip3udpEEEEE"
```

That is the `boost::asio::datagram_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::udp>`, so continue to the next:

```
(gdb) set $service = $service.next_
(gdb) p $service.key_.type_info_.__name
$2 = 0x8052cc0 "N5boost4asio6detail14typeid_wrapperINS1_13epoll_reactorEEE"
```

`$service` now points to the reactor service.  Downcast the service, based on the `init_key` type argument:

```
(gdb) set $service = *('boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor'*) $service
```

The outstanding handlers with work are in an linked list of operations within the reactor:

```
(gdb) set $ops = $service.registered_descriptors_.live_list_.op_queue_
(gdb) set $op = $ops.front_
(gdb) p *$op
$3 = {<boost::asio::detail::task_io_service_operation> = {next_ = 0x0, 
    func_ = 0x804c256
    <boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_recvfrom_op<
    boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1, boost::asio::ip::basic_endpoint<
    boost::asio::ip::udp>, boost::_bi::bind_t<void, 
    boost::_mfi::mf2<void, udp_echo, boost::system::error_code const&, 
    unsigned int>, boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<udp_echo*>,
    boost::arg<1> (*)(), boost::arg<2> (*)()> > >::
    do_complete(boost::asio::io_service::io_service_impl*, 
    boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor::descriptor_state::operation*, 
    boost::system::error_code const&, size_t)>, task_result_ = 0}, ec_ = {
    m_val = 11, m_cat = 0x13b2c8}, bytes_transferred_ = 0, perform_func_ =
    0x80514c8 <boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_recvfrom_op_base<
    boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1,  
    boost::asio::ip::basic_endpoint<boost::asio::ip::udp> 
    >::do_perform(boost::asio::detail::reactor_op*)>}
```

Another downcast is required.  Cast `$op` to the class for which the `func_` member function pointer belongs.

```
(gdb) set $op = *('boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_recvfrom_op<
boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1, boost::asio::ip::basic_endpoint<
boost::asio::ip::udp>, boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf2<
void, udp_echo, boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned int>,
 boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<udp_echo*>, 
 boost::arg<1> (*)(), boost::arg<2> (*)()> > >'*) $op
```

This operation contains the desired information.

The buffer:

```
(gdb) p $op.buffers_ 
$4 = {<boost::asio::mutable_buffer> = {data_ = 0xbfffe77c, 
    size_ = 128}, <No data fields>}
(gdb) p &echo.buffer_
$5 = (boost::array<char, 128u> *) 0xbfffe77c
```

The `this` instance:

```
(gdb) p $op.handler_.l_.a1_.t_ 
$6 = (udp_echo *) 0xbfffe768
(gdb) p &echo
$7 = (udp_echo *) 0xbfffe768
```

The member function pointer:

```
(gdb) p $op.handler_.f_.f_
$8 = (void (udp_echo::*)(udp_echo *, const boost::system::error_code &, 
    unsigned int)) 0x80505b0 <
    udp_echo::handle_receive(boost::system::error_code const&, size_t)>
```

Socket information:

```
(gdb) p $op.socket_ 
$9 = 10
(gdb) p echo.socket_.implementation.socket_ 
$10 = 10
```

In this case, the operation only knows about the native socket representation (the file descriptor).  One helpful way to determine what socket it is, is to query lsof.

```
$/usr/sbin/lsof -i -P | grep a.out 
a.out     4265 ghost   10u  IPv4 1166143       UDP *:4321
```

Thus, file descriptor 10 is listening on UDP 4321.

Comment: Once more, thank you very much for thorough answer. I managed to find registered_descriptors_.live_list_.op_queue_ myself. The downcast was the thing I was missing. I had little time to read boost::asio code and was not able to figure it out. Could you elaborate on why is this downcast needed? Also I assume you use version 1.47; I use 1.51 and last step differs a bit : $op.handler_.handler_ is needed.

Comment: I was building against a recent pull of the trunk.  Downcast are needed because only the most derived operation contains all the types and members to extract the desired data.  The base classes for operations do not have type information about the user handler, allowing the reactor to operation on operations generically.

Comment: GDB may require ``set print object`` to see all the vtables info.