# blocked requests in io_service

Tags: boost-asio

I have implemented client server program using boost::asio library.
In my implementation there are times when io_service.run() blocks indefinitely. In case I pass another request to io_service, the blocked call begins to execute normally.

Is there any way to see what are the pending requests inside the io_service queue ?

I have not used work object to block the run call!

Comment: Not that i knew of. Without knowing what you do, it is hard to find out what blocks you. Did you fork your application? Is any of your handlers not returning? A deadline_timer not cancelled? If you cannot find anything, you could always use more than one io_service. Maybe one per socket so you can hunt down the offending call. You could also `stop` your io_service when you believe everything has been done. Or you just cancel every other async operation in your handlers and restart them if needed. Or do not `run` but `poll` so you keep control of what happens when.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no official ways to query into the `io_service` to find all pending request.  However, there are a few techniques to debug the problem:

- Boost 1.47 introduced [handler tracking](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/handler_tracking.html). Simply define `BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_HANDLER_TRACKING` and Boost.Asio will write debug output, including timestamps, an identifier, and the operation type, to the standard error stream.
- Attach a debugger dig through the layers to find and examine operation queues.  This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15418025/1053968) covers both understanding handler tracking and using a debugger to examine an operation queue for the `epoll_reactor`.

Finally, if you believe it is a bug, then it may be worth updating to the latest version or checking the [revision history](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/history.html) for relevant changes.  Regardless, describing the problem in more detail may allow others to help identify the source of the problem and potential solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Now i spent a few hours reading and experimenting (i need more boost::asio functionality for work as well) and it turns out: Kind of.
But it is not as straightforward or readable as one might hope.

Under the hood (well, under the outermost hood) io_service has a bunch of other services registered, which do the work `async_` operations of their respective fields require.
These are the "Services" described in the reference.
Now sadly, the services stay registered, wether there is work to do or not. For example if your io_service has a udp socket, it will still have all the corresponding services, even if the socket itself is inactive.

But you can ask your io_service which services it has. Lets say you want to know wether your io_service called `m_io_service` has an udp `datagram_socket_service`. Then you can call something like:

```
if (boost::asio::has_service<boost::asio::datagram_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::udp> >(m_io_service))
{
    //Whatever
}
```

That does not help a lot, because it will be true no matter wether the socket is active or not. But after you know, that you have that service, you can get a ref to it using `use_service` instead of `has_service` but with the same elegant amount of <>.
And now you can inspect the service to see what it is up to. Sadly, it will not tell you what the outstanding handlers names are (probably partly because it does not know them) but if it is a socket, you can get its `implemention_type` and with that check whether it currently `is_open` or find either the `local_endpoint` as well as the `remote_endpoint`.

In case of a `deadline_timer_service` you can, among other stuff, find out when it `expires_at`.

See the reference for more information what the service is and is not willing to tell you.
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference.html

This information should then hopefully allow you to determine which `async_` operation did not return.
And if not, at the very least you can `cancel` any unexpectedly active services.